# How to communicate with a dockerized .net core console app?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm playing around with docker in Visual Studio. I have a console app which runs in docker and I'd like to communicate with it.

docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile are standard ones, generated by VS

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  publisher:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}publisher
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Publisher/Dockerfile
```

Publisher/Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Publisher/Publisher.csproj Publisher/
RUN dotnet restore Publisher/Publisher.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Publisher
RUN dotnet build Publisher.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Publisher.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Publisher.dll"]
```

Publisher:

```
namespace Publisher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World, I'm a publisher!");

            while(true)
            {
                var line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(line.ToUpper());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write to publisher app standard input. Running `docker attach my_publisher`, the console isn't accepting my input at all. After I detach from the container the input mentioned above is typed to my console.

I tried changing my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  publisher:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}publisher
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Publisher/Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true # HERE
    tty: true        # AND HERE
```

Now it seems to accept my input (it doesn't get typed to my console after I detach), but I see no output, so I'm not sure.

So what should I do to be able to type input to my app as well as read output?